# Macro to skip filtered rows

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have the following macro which does the following:

- Get the file names from a folder on Windows - this is only done if the list and folder is sorted A to Z
- Combines the name with the folder name
- Hyperlinks the conjoined names

  ```
  Dim xFSO As Object

  Dim xFolder As Object

  Dim xFile As Object

  Dim xFiDialog As FileDialog

  Dim xPath As String

  Dim i As Integer

  Set xFiDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

  If xFiDialog.Show = -1 Then

      xPath = xFiDialog.SelectedItems(1)

  End If

  Set xFiDialog = Nothing

  If xPath = "" Then Exit Sub

  Set xFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set xFolder = xFSO.GetFolder(xPath)

  i = 1 'to start on row 2 and keep the heading cell

  For Each xFile In xFolder.Files

      i = i + 1

      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 3), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name

      Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 4) & "\" & Cells(i, 3) '5/4/3 is the columns here

      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 5), Address:=Cells(i, 5).Formula

  Next

  End Sub
  ```

Is it possible to add something to the macro that will skip filtered rows in the spreadsheet?
320 rows in total and 20 are filtered out but not consecutively (9/66/82/108/309) filtered out?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Super User!

I believe the best path forward on this will be to wrap your actions inside of your `for` loop with an `if` statement that checks for the `hidden` property. Here is the complete code:

```
Sub test()

Dim xFSO As Object

Dim xFolder As Object

Dim xFile As Object

Dim xFiDialog As FileDialog

Dim xPath As String

Dim i As Integer

Set xFiDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If xFiDialog.Show = -1 Then

    xPath = xFiDialog.SelectedItems(1)

End If

Set xFiDialog = Nothing

If xPath = "" Then Exit Sub

Set xFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set xFolder = xFSO.GetFolder(xPath)

i = 1 'to start on row 2 and keep the heading cell

For Each xFile In xFolder.Files

    i = i + 1
    
    If Rows(i).Hidden <> True Then  'check if current row is hidden; if not, take action

        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 3), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name
    
        Cells(i, 5).Value = Cells(i, 4) & "\" & Cells(i, 3) '5/4/3 is the columns here
    
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 5), Address:=Cells(i, 5).Formula
        
    End If

Next

End Sub
```